# How to put an effect on my logos?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

I want to put two logos in my copyright section: first one; on hover, shows the bank logos with their own caption (the text that apprears above the logos and explains what it is.. think of it like a tooltip) on the right. the second, on hover, should show the payment cards like visa, master etc. with their captions. what code should i write to apply this effect on it?

I want it to have an effect.. for example it should transit to the right then shows the logos and the caption.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "captions"? Names? Explanations?

Comment: Hi, **welcome to Stack Overflow**, please consider **editing your title** to reflect your problem, instead of "How to put *this effect*", be specific. Users that are looking at the list of questions must be able to understand what your specific problem is without having to click and read everything ! :) Also consider **adding a screenshot** to explain what result you would like to have, along with **any code** or **research** you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve by using bootstrap or any other library since the functionalities are mostly same as a tooltip.

**Please go through this**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

**Example / demo**

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Cool logo!!!"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ym9byyf/